# Extended gage R&R for attribute data

Tags: quality-control

I would like to see a worked example of doing an expanded gage R&R study. Expanded means the gage is varied, as well as the parts, operators, and trials that vary in a standard GR&R study. Attribute means the measured data is pass/fail instead of continuous data such as length in a standard GR&R study. Is there an existing publication or template on this?